# Segurança em formulário

Tags: php, segurança

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

PHP (servidor):

```
if(isset($_POST['subdate']) && !empty($_POST['date'])) {

   $daysOff = array();
   $get_date = explode(',', $_POST['date']);
   foreach ($get_date as $date) {
     $date = explode('-', $date);
     $day = $date[0];
     $month = $date[1];
     $year = $date[2];
     $time_Stamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
     $daysOff[] = strftime('%d-%m-%Y', $time_Stamp);
   }

   $daysOff = json_encode($daysOff);
   echo "dates off: " .$daysOff;
}

else {
   $daysOff = json_encode(array("23-09-2015", "15-09-2015"));
   echo "dates off: " .$daysOff;
}
```

HTML (cliente)

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
...
<form method="POST">
    <input id="datepicker" type="date" name="date" autocomplete="off" readonly>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="subdate">
</form>
...
```

Javascript (cliente)

```
function datePicker() {

   <?php echo "var datesOff = JSON.parse('" .$daysOff. "');"; ?>
   var daysSelected = [];

   var datepickerOpts = {

      beforeShowDay: function(date){

         var day = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
         var checkDate = datesOff.indexOf(day);

         if(checkDate == -1) {
             // not found, data available
             return [true, "", "available"];
         }
         else {
            return [false, "", "not available"];
         }
      },
      onSelect: function(date) {

         var index = daysSelected.indexOf(date);

         if(index == -1){
            daysSelected.push(date);
            console.log(daysSelected);
         }
         else {
            daysSelected.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(daysSelected);
         }
         $('input[type="date"]').val(daysSelected);
         // prevent from closing datepicker when clicking date
         $(this).data('datepicker')['inline'] = true;
      },
      onClose: function() {
         $(this).data('datepicker')['inline'] = false;
      },
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImage: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/256/Time-And-Date-Calendar-icon.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",
      showAnim: "slideDown",
   };

   $('#datepicker').datepicker(datepickerOpts);
}

datePicker();
```

Tudo funciona muito bem, partindo do príncipio que não vão mudar manualmente o valor do input como mostro na imagem abaixo, o que faz disparar um erro no servidor, mais especificamente com a função explode. Eu queria evitar isso, gostava que houvesse uma simples verificação (já tentei com try/catch), ex: se os inputs fossem este formato: `"dd-mm-aaa,dd-mm-aaaa"` é que avançamos para os explodes etc... Tendo em mente que tem de resultar também se só houver uma data: `"dd-mm-aaaa"`. Outras sugestões para evitar que sejam disparados erros neste caso também são bem vindas. Exemplo do que acontece:

Antes de submeter, mudar manualmente o valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de submeter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erros surgem quando tentamos aceder aos indexes (keys) de `$date`, dentro do ciclo que temos no código do lado servidor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maioria dos seus problemas serão resolvidos com algumas simples validações, exemplo:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['subdate']) && !empty($_POST['date'])) {

   $daysOff = array();
   $get_date = explode(',', $_POST['date']);
   foreach ($get_date as $date) {

      // Validação com Expressão Regular
      // Apenas com essa validação você pode resolver a maioria dos seus problemas
      if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4})$/', $date)){
         // Não está no formato NN-NN-NNNN
         // Tome qualquer providencia aqui
      }

      $date = explode('-', $date);

      // Validando a quantidade de elementos retornados pelo explode
      if (count($date) == 3){
         $day = $date[0];
         $month = $date[1];
         $year = $date[2];
         $time_Stamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
         $daysOff[] = strftime('%d-%m-%Y', $time_Stamp);
      } else {
         // O explode não resultou em 3 elementos
         // Tome qualquer providencia aqui
      }
   }

   $daysOff = json_encode($daysOff);
   echo "dates off: " .$daysOff;
} else {
   $daysOff = json_encode(array("23-09-2015", "15-09-2015"));
   echo "dates off: " .$daysOff;
}
```

Comentei o código mostrando as validações. Tenha em mente uma coisa, **sempre que receber dados do usuário/cliente, mesmo que por uma biblioteca javascript é crucial validar esses dados**. Qualquer dado de entrada deve ser validado pelo sistema, ainda mais quando o processo depende desses dados.

Ainda poderia fazer outras validações, pra verificar se os dados realmente são datas: [Correctly determine if date string is a valid date in that format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format)

Comment: Obgado, era uma solução como ess que procurava, simples e capaz de ter o trabalho feito. mas não está a aceitar as datas certas também, mas creio que com um pouco de correção consiga

Comment: Já está a resultar, enganou-se em `[0-2]{4})$` devia ser também `[0-9]...`. Já agora que quer dizer o `^`, `/`, "\", `$` no preg match? Obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: Verdade, me enganei ali no `[0-2]{4}`, já corrigi. `^` quer dizer "início", `/` são delimitadores da expressão regular, `$` quer dizer "fim" e `\ ` é o escape para o carácter literal `-` que contém na data, essa barra não é absolutamente necessária, mas é bom para evitar possíveis bugs e erros @Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Bem, como você trabalha com formulários e não sabemos o que o cliente vai passar seria bom para evitar varios erros, adicionar uma [mascara](http://www.igorescobar.com/blog/2012/03/13/mascaras-com-jquery-mask-plugin/) de date no seu input.
Outra coisa que costumo fazer no meu codigo é sempre usar [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) do php, uma dica para você trabalhar com a data seria mais ou menos assim no parametro de entrada.

Ex:
$newDate = [implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)('-', [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php)([explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)('/', $date)));

$newDate = new [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)($newDate);

E no parametro de saida você adiciona um tratamento para o date.

Comment: Jose seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, [leia esse tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para conhecer melhor o modelo de formatação de perguntas do SOpt, assim melhora a qualidade da sua resposta e de toda a comunidade no geral.